# Grab user Location on Facebook and append HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, geolocation

How would I grab the user's location from Facebook using Graph API within a FB tab?

Something like this:

```
if (countryName = 'US') {
    $("#footer a h3").html("www.ok.com");
} else {
    $("#footer a h3").html("www.facebook.com");
}
```

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use geoPlugin API for that, here is an example code,

```
function setHTML(ip) {
    var url = "http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip="+ip+"&jsoncallback=?";
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        if (data.geoplugin_countryCode == 'US') {
            $("div").html("www.ok.com");
        } else {
            $("div").html("www.facebook.com");
        }         
    });
}

function changeHTML(ip) {
    var url = "http://jsonip.appspot.com/?callback=?";
    if(!ip) {
       $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
           setHTML(data.ip);
       });            
    } else {
       setHTML(ip);
    }
}

// USAGE
changeHTML("73.111.126.13"); // specific IP
changeHTML(); // Find current user IP with appspot
```

[And here is a DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5Yfd6/1/)

Comment: you've changed your question while I was writing answer, so this is an answer for your not updated question. sorry for that and glad to help.

Comment: Sorry about that, it should still work within a Facebook Tab no? - works fine locally.

Comment: @user1381806, yes it should work anyway, but it's not using graph-api. I don't know how you can do that, but that would be more easy with graph-api.